# new installation thinks it is 2018

Tags: latex-misc, tlmgr

I installed current TexLive afresh on a new HD under Devuan beowulf. The file I've been working on has \usepackage{siunitx) in preamble, but after with the re-installation when I run latex on it under emacs I get: Error: File `siunitx.sty' not found. I realized I had not copied the TeX packages from my old disk to the new.

So I ran $ tlmgr --gui  and do "Load Default" from the ctan mirror. But get error: "Loading of remote database failed. Error message: Remote repository is newer than local (2018 < 2020)". The problem this is I'm running TeXLive 20200731. Two years ago I did run the 2018 version.

So I proceed to update my database by downloding and unzipping
update-tlmgr-latest.sh. I do have /bin/sh. Here is what I get:

Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing TeX Live Manager Updater  100%
./runme.sh: Cannot find TeX Live root using kpsewhich
--var-value=SELFAUTOPARENT.
./runme.sh: (no tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb and/or tlpkg/tlpobj/.)
./runme.sh: Please set your PATH as needed, otherwise it's hopeless.

I try
$ tlmgr update --self
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
tlmgr: Remote repository is newer than local (2018 < 2020)
Cross release updates are only supported with
update-tlmgr-latest(.sh/.exe) --update
Please see https://tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html for details.

The configuration:

(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
===================== version information =======================
tlmgr revision 49885 (2019-01-31 20:27:00 +0100)
tlmgr using installation: /usr/share/texlive
...
PATH: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
...
kpsewhich: /usr/bin/kpsewhich
...
TEXCONFIG={{}/home/haines/.texlive2018/texmf-config,/home/haines/...
...
== kpathsea variables from environment only (ok if no output here)

So it seems my TeXLive as 2018. In /home/haines there is no longer any .texlfive directory.
In ~/.profile there is:

PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2020/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH; export PATH

Comment: `PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2020/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH` would be the default location for a vanilla texlive installed from TUG,  `running on Debian, switching to user mode` implies that you are using a debian packaged texlive (which should be updated with apt packages not tlmgr. Do you have two conflicting installations?

Answer (score 1):

If you installed TeX Live through `apt`, it updates through `apt`, not `tlmgr`.  You might have more than one TeX Live installation in your PATH.  Check `which tlmgr` to find out which one you are actually running.  Also check the version you installed, using `apt show texlive-base`.

If you installed your own, up-to-date version, you want to make sure it is in your PATH and remove the others.  [There are instructions here.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/553305/61644)

You also would not want to run `tlmgr` from your user account in any case.  You should create a `tex` system account (or `texlive`) and run your installers and updates as that.  You should, however, be running programs like `lualatex` and `latex` without `sudo`.

Comment: I did full deletion of TeXLive and resinstalled carefully. Now linux command not in PATH. So I do: $ /usr/local/texlive/2020/bin/x86_64-linuIx$ ./pdftex sample2e.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=pdftex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
! I can't write on file `sample2e.log'.
(Press Enter to retry, or Control-D to exit; default file extension is `.log')

Comment: @HainesBrown I’m not able to understand your comment. Sorry.

Comment: Simply that with the full install with the downloaded installer .gz file I I can no longer run the $ latex command. Because the failure of my TeXLive to work it is interfering seriously with my work, I'm temped to do another removal and just install the stable texlive-full from my operating system repository. Any reason I shouldn't?

Comment: @HainesBrown There’s a typo in the path you gave `x86_64_linulx`, which might be the problem. Just adding the command `PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2020/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH` to your profile ought to work; I linked to directions that might be more complicated than what you need.

Comment: That said, `sudo apt install texlive-full` ought to work fine with less effort.

Comment: Also, run latex commands from a project directory you’re able to write to. It can’t create its log or aux files in a system directory.

Comment: Davislor, I want to thank your for your comments. I preferred not to download texlive-full from my operating system (Devuan fork of Debian) is cautiously slow in adopting new material. I worry that its version 2018.20190227-2 might not handle LuaLaTeX well.

Answer (score 0):

Finally had success. The problem I had testing Tex Live by issuing a latex command was because foolishly I did not log out/in to make the paths defined in .profile operative. Have no idea the reason for the original problem except that somewhere there was a link that presumed an earlier version of TeX Live. I did a radical cleansing of my old installation of TeX Live and downloaded the installer again in order to reinstall.